# Nodejs open a file get the file names and then take the screenshot of each file

Tags: node.js

I have a reports folder, where execution reports in HTML Format will be added. The count of individual HTML files varies. I need to read each file name and then take the screenshot of each file.

```
const webpageCapture = require("webpage-capture");
const capturer = new webpageCapture.default();
const testFolder = './Report/';
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('reportName.txt',"");
fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    file = file.split('.')[0];
    fs.appendFileSync('reportName.txt', file + `\r\n`);
});
nbLines = ('reportName.txt'.split("\n")).length;
console.log(nbLines)
var array = fs.readFileSync('reportName.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    capturer.file(array[i]+".html", i+".png", {
        waitFor: 1500,
        viewport: {
            width: 1200,
            height: 1000
        }
    })
    capturer.close();
}
```

what I tried is a bit complicated. I read the filenames in Report and then saved each name as a new line to file. Then read that file and then passed each name to take screenshot. But unfortunately it was not working.

the for loop is not getting end and o screenshot taken

Comment: "Was not working". How?

Comment: @Phix - it was printing filename as .html<FileName>

Comment: Please don't ever iterate the elements of an array with `for(i in array)`, even more so, when `i` isn't even a declared variable.  In modern Javascript, use `for (let item of array)`.